# war deployment on Tomcat with error java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: grails.async.web.AsyncGrailsWebRequest

Tags: tomcat, grails, war

I am developing a rest-api application with the following configuration and run with grails run-app without any issue.

```
grails version: 3.3.x (tried with 3.3.5,3.3.10,3.3.11)
tomcat version: 8.5.56
java version: 1.8.0_252
profile: "org.grails.profiles:rest-api"
```

However, when I run

```
> grails prod run-app
```

or deploy the war file created by grails war to tomcat, I encounter the same error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: grails.async.web.AsyncGrailsWebRequest
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
```

Any idea or suggestion to resolve this issue ?  Thx in advance.

Below is the build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.grails:grails-gradle-plugin:$grailsVersion"
        classpath "org.grails.plugins:hibernate5:6.0.4"
        classpath "org.grails.plugins:views-gradle:1.1.2"

    }
}


version "2.0"
group "hapi"

apply plugin:"eclipse"
apply plugin:"idea"
apply plugin:"war"
apply plugin:"org.grails.grails-web"
apply plugin:"org.grails.plugins.views-json"


repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
}

ext['tomcat.version'] = '8.5.56'

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.grails:grails-bom:$grailsVersion"
    }
    applyMavenExclusions false
}

dependencies {
    provided "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure"
    compile "org.grails:grails-core"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-url-mappings"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-rest"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-codecs"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-interceptors"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-services"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-datasource"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-databinding"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-async"
    compile "org.grails:grails-web-boot"
    compile "org.grails:grails-logging"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:cache"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:hibernate5"
    compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.1.16.Final"
    compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache:5.1.16.Final"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:views-json"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:views-json-templates"
    console "org.grails:grails-console"
    profile "org.grails.profiles:rest-api"

    runtime "org.postgresql:postgresql:9.4.1212"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:postgresql-extensions:4.6.6"
    
    compile 'org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:3.2.3'
    compile "org.grails.plugins:spring-security-rest:2.0.0.RC1"
    
    compile "com.github.groovy-wslite:groovy-wslite:1.1.2"
    testCompile "org.grails:grails-plugin-testing"
    testCompile "org.grails.plugins:geb"
    testCompile "org.grails:grails-datastore-rest-client"
    testRuntime "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-htmlunit-driver:2.47.1"
    testRuntime "net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit:2.18"
    
    //compile "org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-ant:2.4.7"

    compile fileTree(dir: 'lib', include: '*.jar')
}
```

Below is the list of jar files in the WEB-INF/lib

```
accessors-smart-1.2.jar
antlr-2.7.7.jar
aopalliance-1.0.jar
apns.jar
asm-5.0.4.jar
bcpkix-jdk15on-1.55.jar
bcprov-jdk15on-1.55.jar
cache-4.0.0.jar
cas-client-core-3.5.0.jar
cas-client-support-saml-3.4.1.jar
classmate-1.3.4.jar
commons-codec-1.10.jar
commons-collections-3.2.2.jar
commons-fileupload-1.3.3.jar
commons-io-2.2.jar
commons-lang-2.6.jar
commons-logging-1.2.jar
commons-validator-1.5.1.jar
concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru-1.4.2.jar
converters-3.3.1.jar
dom4j-1.6.1.jar
ehcache-2.10.4.jar
geronimo-jta_1.1_spec-1.1.1.jar
grails-bootstrap-3.3.5.jar
grails-codecs-3.3.5.jar
grails-core-3.3.5.jar
grails-databinding-3.3.5.jar
grails-datastore-core-6.1.9.RELEASE.jar
grails-datastore-gorm-6.1.9.RELEASE.jar
grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate-core-6.1.9.RELEASE.jar
grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate5-6.1.9.RELEASE.jar
grails-datastore-gorm-support-6.1.9.RELEASE.jar
grails-datastore-gorm-validation-6.1.9.RELEASE.jar
grails-datastore-web-6.1.9.RELEASE.jar
grails-encoder-3.3.5.jar
grails-gsp-3.3.1.jar
grails-logging-3.3.5.jar
grails-plugin-codecs-3.3.5.jar
grails-plugin-controllers-3.3.5.jar
grails-plugin-databinding-3.3.5.jar
grails-plugin-datasource-3.3.5.jar
grails-plugin-domain-class-3.3.5.jar
grails-plugin-i18n-3.3.5.jar
grails-plugin-interceptors-3.3.5.jar
grails-plugin-mimetypes-3.3.5.jar
grails-plugin-rest-3.3.5.jar
grails-plugin-services-3.3.5.jar
grails-plugin-url-mappings-3.3.5.jar
grails-plugin-validation-3.3.5.jar
grails-spring-3.3.5.jar
grails-taglib-3.3.1.jar
grails-validation-3.3.5.jar
grails-web-3.3.5.jar
grails-web-boot-3.3.5.jar
grails-web-common-3.3.5.jar
grails-web-databinding-3.3.5.jar
grails-web-gsp-3.3.1.jar
grails-web-mvc-3.3.5.jar
grails-web-sitemesh-3.3.1.jar
grails-web-taglib-3.3.1.jar
grails-web-url-mappings-3.3.5.jar
groovy-2.4.15.jar
groovy-all-2.4.15.jar
groovy-json-2.4.15.jar
groovy-sql-2.4.15.jar
groovy-templates-2.4.15.jar
groovy-wslite-1.1.2.jar
groovy-xml-2.4.15.jar
gson-2.8.2.jar
guava-21.0.jar
hibernate-commons-annotations-5.0.1.Final.jar
hibernate-core-5.1.16.Final.jar
hibernate-ehcache-5.1.16.Final.jar
hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar
hibernate-validator-5.3.6.Final.jar
hibernate5-6.1.9.jar
jackson-annotations-2.8.0.jar
jackson-core-2.8.11.jar
jackson-databind-2.8.11.1.jar
jandex-2.0.3.Final.jar
javassist-3.21.0-GA.jar
javax.el-api-2.2.4.jar
jboss-logging-3.3.2.Final.jar
jcip-annotations-1.0-1.jar
jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.25.jar
joda-time-2.9.9.jar
json-smart-2.3.jar
jta-1.1.jar
jul-to-slf4j-1.7.25.jar
log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.25.jar
logback-classic-1.1.11.jar
logback-core-1.1.11.jar
nimbus-jose-jwt-4.36.jar
pac4j-cas-2.2.1.jar
pac4j-core-2.2.1.jar
pac4j-oauth-2.2.1.jar
postgresql-9.4.1212.jar
postgresql-extensions-4.6.6.jar
scribejava-apis-3.3.0.jar
scribejava-core-3.3.0.jar
serializer-2.7.2.jar
sitemesh-2.4.jar
slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar
snakeyaml-1.17.jar
spring-aop-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar
spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar
spring-boot-1.5.12.RELEASE.jar
spring-boot-actuator-1.5.12.RELEASE.jar
spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.12.RELEASE.jar
spring-boot-starter-1.5.12.RELEASE.jar
spring-boot-starter-actuator-1.5.12.RELEASE.jar
spring-boot-starter-logging-1.5.12.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-support-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar
spring-core-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar
spring-expression-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar
spring-jdbc-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar
spring-orm-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-core-3.2.3.jar
spring-security-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-rest-2.0.0.RC1.jar
spring-security-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-tx-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar
spring-web-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar
spring-webmvc-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar
tomcat-embed-logging-log4j-8.5.2.jar
validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar
views-core-1.2.7.jar
views-json-1.2.7.jar
views-json-templates-1.2.7.jar
xml-apis-1.4.01.jar
```

Comment: If you unpack the war file (using unzip or jar utility), what libraries are present in its WEB-INF/lib directory?

Comment: I added the file list in the original post.  Thx.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, need to change

```
compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-async"
```

to

```
compile "org.grails.plugins:async"
```